# Angular : is it possible to pass an array or multiple strings to the $on event listener so as not to have multiple lines of listeners?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, controller, event-listener

i have something like:

```
$scope.$on(config.SOME_CONSTANT, ()=> {
    activate();
    // plus a bunch of instantiations
    $scope.$digest();
});

$scope.$on(config.SOME_OTHER_CONSTANT, ()=> {
    activate();
    $scope.$digest();
});
```

is it possible to consolidate them into 1 listener so as to be more dry? the angular docs say it only takes a string arg... i have some of conditional stuff that i would like to happen in both cases of the event occurrence. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with a loop :) Working [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/uberspeck/c2apC/)

```
angular.forEach(['one', 'two', 'three'], function(value) {
  $scope.$on(value, function(event) {
    console.log(event.name);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object like, for example:

```
var myApp = { 'id': "myApplicationId", 'name': "myApplicationName"}
```